# Shooting out a Virus with W key (Ogar Server)

Tags: agar.io

How can you shoot viruses with the W key? I have seen multiple servers do this, and I was wondering how. I'm using an Ogar server, and I'm sure I need to add some code somewhere.

If I'm not clear, I want to be able to press W and a small virus will come out. Instead of mass, it will be a small virus.

And I'm not sure how to customize the W skin, to look like a small virus.

Check an example out here: http://agar.io/?ip=vps56296.vps.ovh.ca:443

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It's a gamemode in OgarUltimateMaster.

Answer (score 2):

You shoot viruses with the <kbd>w</kbd> key as you mentioned.

It is similar to splitting, you need to have a minimum mass before you can do it.

If you can't do it currently, then continue increasing your mass and then try again, you'll be able to do it with some more mass.

Comment: Let me show you the server as an example.

Press W:  http://agar.io/?ip=vps56296.vps.ovh.ca:443

Comment: private servers can implement any rules they want they may not allow the ability to shoot viruses

Comment: This is a private server I'm making.

Comment: https://github.com/OgarPlus/Ogar-Plus

Comment: I have that, is there a place where this is found?